# How to access PHPMyAdmin from the web on a VPS (IaaS) server environment?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, alias, phpmyadmin, file-shortcut

Ubuntu server 22.10.
If PHPMyAdmin doesn’t have this path `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` then how could I access it from `https://IP-ADDRESS/phpmyadmin?`

I thought about creating a softlink from `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` to `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` but if I understand correctly such soft link is not the standard way and there is some kind of an “alias” that needs to be added to the Apache2 conf.

Comment: While the question was closed for lack of clarity, I voted for "better suitable for another site". It is clear, but it's much better for https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

The alias is already prepared for you by the phpmyadmin package. You use `a2enconf phpmyadmin` to enable the prepared configuration file from `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`.